# Animation doesn't work in Python

Tags: python, linux, animation, matplotlib

Where is normal explanation on how to plot animated graphs in Python?

I wrote this

```
from pylab import *
import time

ion()

tstart = time.time()               # for profiling
x = arange(0,2*pi,0.01)            # x-array
line, = plot(x,sin(x))
for i in arange(1,200000):
    line.set_ydata(sin(x+i/10.0))  # update the data
    draw()                         # redraw the canvas

print('FPS:', 200/(time.time()-tstart))
```

and got just white window

[image]

Comment: To answer your actual question: https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
from pylab import *
import time

ion()

tstart = time.time()               # for profiling
x = arange(0,2*pi,0.01)            # x-array
line, = plot(x,sin(x))
for i in arange(1,200000):
    line.set_ydata(sin(x+i/10.0))  # update the data
    draw()                         # redraw the canvas
    pause(0.5)
```

With `pause` time in second