# plot updated dendogram with matplotlib

Tags: python

I'm generating a dendogram using the `dendogram` function from `scipy.cluster.hierarchy`. I create the dendogram and plot it using:

```
linkage_matrix = ward(dist) 
dendrogram(linkage_matrix, orientation="left", labels=names) 

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Everything works fine until now. What I want to do, is to update the leaf labels of the dendogram and plot a new dendogram. I tried two ways:

1. Using the `leaf_label_func` as mentioned here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html

but this is not working well. I'm getting an error that `n` does not exist, which is actually True. There is no `n` in the function.

2. Updating the dendogram list of names manually, and then added it to the dendogram.

`

```
    linkage_matrix = ward(dist)

dend = dendrogram(linkage_matrix, orientation="left", labels=names)

leaf_names = dend['ivl']

for idx, item in enumerate(leaf_names):
    if 'c' in item:
        item = item+'_c'
        leaf_names[idx] = item

    if 'i' in item:
        item = item+'_i'
        leaf_names[idx] = item

dend['ivl'] = leaf_names


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

`
```

However, the plot that is showing is still the older version of the dendogram, but if i `print(dend)`, the new leaf names seem to be there. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: you need to update your plot here an example with an other kind of plot but the logic should be the same : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45946607/animation-doesnt-work-in-python/45946682#45946682

Comment: i tried this, doesnt seem to work. Can you please show me where to use this in my code? @Dadep

Answer (score 0):

An example of updating `dendogram` you can adapt to your need :

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import time
ion()
for i in range(10):  
    #update here your dendogram values :
    dist=[12.12,15.485,18.45,4.4,13.684,float(i+1)]
    Z=linkage(dist)
    # calculate it again :
    dendrogram(Z, orientation="left") 
    # draw it again :
    draw()
    #wait 1 second between two update :
    pause(1)
```

Comment: this doesnt work on my code, I was able to make your code work, but when I try to apply it to my code, the second draw is doing nothing.

Comment: can you edit your post with what you tried ? The problem should come from the way you modify your dendrogram.

Comment: I modify the dendogram inside the for loop as shown in my post. I added a draw before and after I update the dendogram, the first one works, the second one does not.

Comment: the problem is that in the `for` loop you show in your code you do not update your dendogram, you only update `leaf_names` ...  look how the code is done in my post : **inside a loop :**  first you change the value use to build your dendogram, then you build your dendogram, then you draw it, and then you **must** have a pause.

Comment: I found a way of solving this using the link here: https://codexample.org/questions/391789/scipy-dendrogram-leaf-label-colours.c